# How to take the derivative of this likelihood function?

Tags: probability, statistics, derivatives

$$
\ln p(D|\mu) = \sum_{n=1}^N \ln p(x_n |\mu) = \sum_{n=1}^N \{x_n \ln \mu + (1 - x_n \ln(1-\mu)\}
$$

And I know the derivative is equal to zero at the mean but I cant get the steps right to get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's differentiate it,

$$\frac1{\hat{\mu}}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n-\frac1{1-\hat{\mu}}\sum_{n=1}^N (1-x_n)=0$$

$$\frac1{\hat{\mu}}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n=\frac1{1-\hat{\mu}}\left(N-\sum_{n=1}^N x_n\right)$$

Divide by $N$ throughout,

$$\frac{\bar{x}}{\hat{\mu}}=\frac{1-\bar{x}}{1-\hat{\mu}}$$

Now, try to solve for $\hat{\mu}$.

Comment: Never thought to do the sums that way. Thanks